# what does _the_hidden_goal_ error message mean

Tags: coq

EDIT: I included the proof.

I copied a proof (a proof taken from software foundations) from one file to another file. In the original file, everything compiled fine. In the new file, the error:

```
Hs is used in hypothesis _the_hidden_goal_.
```

is caused by the line

```
rewrite H in Hs.
```

What does this mean? The only information I have found after googling "_the_hidden_goal_" is [here](https://sympa.inria.fr/sympa/arc/ssreflect/2016-01/msg00006.html). As per that link, I changed the offending line to

```
rewrite H in Hs *.
```

and now it compiles, but I don't understand why.

Thank you.

EDITS:

Here is the proof that is causing the problem with the * included.

`Lemma eqb_string_true_iff : forall x y : string,
    eqb_string x y = true <-> x = y.
Proof.
   intros x y.
   unfold eqb_string.
   destruct (string_dec x y) as [H |Hs].
   - subst. split. reflexivity. reflexivity.
   - split.
     + intros contra. discriminate contra.
     + intros H. rewrite H in Hs *. destruct Hs. reflexivity.
Qed.`

The issue still occurs in a file containing only the proof, eqb_string, and some import statements. Here is the total content of the file.

```
From Coq Require Import Bool.Bool Init.Nat Arith.Arith Arith.EqNat
     Init.Datatypes Lists.List Strings.String.
Require Export Coq.Strings.String.
From mathcomp Require Import ssreflect ssrfun ssrbool eqtype.
Import ListNotations.
Open Scope string_scope.

Definition eqb_string (x y : string) : bool :=
  if string_dec x y then true else false.


Lemma eqb_string_true_iff : forall x y : string,
    eqb_string x y = true <-> x = y.
Proof.
   intros x y.
   unfold eqb_string.
   destruct (string_dec x y) as [H |Hs].
   - subst. split. reflexivity. reflexivity.
   - split.
     + intros contra. discriminate contra.
     + intros H. rewrite H in Hs. destruct Hs. reflexivity.
Qed.
Close Scope string_scope.
```

Comment: What's the proof that you copied?

Comment: +1. If it is an exercise from SF, it would be nice if you could try to reproduce the failure in something unrelated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you type `rewrite H in Hs`, SSReflect roughly executes it as follow:

```
set (_the_hidden_goal_ := _). (* hide the goal to prevent rewriting in it *)
revert Hs. (* put the hypothesis in the goal to rewrite in it *)
pattern x. (* extract the left-hand side of the equality *)
case H. (* perform the actual rewriting *)
intros Hs. (* put back the hypothesis in the context *)
unfold _the_hidden_goal_. (* restore the goal *)
```

Since `Hs` occurs in the body of `_the_hidden_goal_`, the call to `revert Hs` fails, hence the error message you get.

By using `rewrite H in Hs *`, you tell SSReflect that you want to rewrite both in `Hs` and in the goal. So, SSReflect skips the first and last steps. This solves the issue.

Note that the only thing specific to SSReflect here is the usage of the name `_the_hidden_goal_`. You would get a similar failure by using Coq's vanilla `rewrite`. More precisely, `rewrite -> H in Hs` complains with the following message: `Cannot change Hs, it is used in conclusion.`

Comment: If this is the case, then how come that line compiles without the star in the software foundations file?

Comment: Does `Hs` appear in the goal at the time of `rewrite H in Hs` in the SF file?

Comment: No, it doesn't! I didn't think to check that because it's the exact same proof in both files, but on a superficial level, the proof state is quite different! In the new file, it says " (if is_left (right Hs)
   then true
   else false) = true", but in the SF file, it says "false = true"! At the exact same point in the proof!

Comment: How can the exact same code behave so differently in two different files?

Comment: Note that `(if is_left (right Hs) then true else false) = true` is only one beta-delta-iota reduction away from `false = true`. So, most tactics might have triggered it. I cannot tell why one of the tactics would behave differently between the two files, though. In your case, it seems like `destruct` behaves differently depending on whether `ssreflect` is imported or not. I have no idea why, and it might be a bug in Coq. Anyway, you can trigger the reduction yourself by calling `simpl` before `rewrite`.